# In python map-reduce, how to print the key with max value?

Tags: python, hadoop

i have a python mapreduce program, which takes an input of lists like this.

```
[0, [199705, 213905, 212829, 13457, 111686, 607393, 872608, 732377, 182538, 787881, 118319, 964795, 166968, 365009, 894771, 613260, 641339, 25337, 34115, 893819, 795572, 685695, 312904, 907582, 871031, 166572, 677524, 579547, 293532, 823144, 475466, 809697, 941561, 691401, 933961, 968512, 533541, 65023, 553086, 644441, 448130, 721938, 404353, 430226, 391164, 805168, 119856, 322218, 657328, 433268]]
[1, [347154, 517159, 919812, 929796, 522835, 759868, 683323, 445616, 940315, 862788, 290265, 955975, 453456, 295093, 884128, 748140, 456509, 449460, 676630, 112028, 891628, 927525, 246077, 249585, 430901, 582551, 889207, 115453, 124599, 985059, 5141, 689344, 396875, 770571, 246748, 643185, 573140, 161546, 734303, 872849, 931835, 793428, 678324, 534229, 928903, 211030, 227042, 669851, 545325, 494357]]
```

There are 20 lists in total. I have to output the maximum integer among all these integers, globally. This is my code.

```
def mapper(key, value):
    print(key,max(value))

def reducer(key, list_of_values):
    print(max(list_of_values))
```

It gives me the output like this. It prints out the biggest integer from each list, and it does so 20 times (20 mappers).

```
955177
957396
968512
972704
977466
982293
982751
983684
985059
987475
988109
988774
995432
995598
996172
996581
997120
998921
999030
999657
```

This is the line from the 20 lists. How can i get the output of only the single biggest integer?

Comment: Are you storing the above lists in another list like this: `globalList = [list1, list2, ..., listN]`?

Comment: no its a json file that contains the integers in separate lists.

Comment: FYI your `reducer` function does nothing with its `key` argument.

Comment: yes i am supposed to print just the biggest integer, i could print the key as well but its not required.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone in the future, there were as many mappers (and reducers) as the number of keys. So i initialized the key variable to 0.

```
def mapper(key, value):
    key = 0
    print key, max(value)
```

That bought the number of reducers to 1, which solved the problem. Thanks @PM2Ring and @timgeb for their responses.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this in pure Python is to use `max` twice with a generator expression. The inner `max` gets the maximum of each sublist, the outer one gets the maximum of those maxima.

```
data = [
    [0, [199705, 213905, 212829, 13457, 111686, 607393, 872608, 732377]],
    [1, [347154, 517159, 919812, 929796, 522835, 759868, 683323, 445616]],
]

print(max(max(u[1]) for u in data))
```

**output**

```
 929796
```

---

You *could* do this in a more functional way:

```
def mapper(row):
    return max(row[1])

print(max(map(mapper, data)))
```

but I think the previous version is more readable, and it's probably faster.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it works when i have all the input in a single data structure. In my case, the input comes in an iterative manner. For each list, mapper gets executed and outputs a max value to the reducer. For the next list, again the max value from that list is sent to the integer. I want a way where i output the biggest value from all the integers, without using a global variable, because the program has to be distributed.

Even if i used your solution, it would print out the output from the current list, and again for the next list, and subsequently for 20 lists.

Comment: @Sid That code (or timgeb's code) will work if `data` is any iterable; it doesn't have to be a list, it could be a generator. If those lists are being produced by separate threads, then we can put them onto a Queue, and then another thread can read the Queue to find the maximum, but then you'll need a way to signal to the Queue reader that there's no more data pending.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but i think that is not necessary (i didnt understand all of it though). Is there a way to emit only a single key from the mapper? If i use the condition `if key>18: print max(value)` it prints out the maximum value for the list associated with key 18. Is there a way i print out the key of the biggest integer?

Comment: I have updated the question, with my complete solution and more input.

Answer (score 0):

At least to me, the canonical solution is to `chain` the lists together in order to have just one iterable of integers. Then apply the `max` function.

```
>>> data = [
    [0, [199705, 213905, 212829, 13457, 111686, 607393, 872608, 732377]],
    [1, [347154, 517159, 919812, 929796, 522835, 759868, 683323, 445616]],
] # example copy-pasted from PM 2Ring :)
>>>
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> max(chain.from_iterable(s[1] for s in data))
929796
```

A little more functional:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> get_second = itemgetter(1)
>>> max(chain.from_iterable(map(get_second, data)))
929796
```

Or without imports:

```
>>> max(number for sublist in data for number in sublist[1])
929796
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it works when i have all the input in a single data structure. In my case, the input comes in an iterative manner. For each list, mapper gets executed and outputs a max value to the reducer. For the next list, again the max value from that list is sent to the integer. I want a way where i output the biggest value from all the integers, without using a global variable, because the program has to be distributed.

Comment: @Sid  "In my case, the input comes in an iterative manner." <- I don't see why that would be a problem. `data` can be any iterable, it does not have to be a list.

Comment: Its not about iterable. What i meant to say was, output comes in an iterative manner as well. Mapper gets executed 20 times, once for each list (actually, key). And it will output current maximum for each list. Which means if i use `max(chain.from_iterable(map(get_first, data)))` in my mapper it will be executed 20 times, outputting a value from each list that comes in as input. Whereas what i want is global maximum, an output from all the lists. For example, if i try `if key=18: print max(value)` it prints out the maximum value from the list with key value 18.

Comment: @Sid sorry, I'm so confused by your design decision that I don't really know how to go from here.

Comment: @Sid. What timgeb said. It would help if you post an [mcve] that shows us how your lists are created and how you want to specify the keys to be involved in the maximum search.

Comment: I have updated the question, with my complete solution and more input.